# script timed out before returning headers openshift

Tags: python, openshift, wsgi, timed

I have a python application (webservice) hosted in Openshift but, a few days ago, the app don't work anymore. The log points to "[error] script timed out before returning headers" and I can't solve this.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was remove the cartridge and install Python 2.6

Comment: This solution worked for me, but it is obviously a bug. Is it reported to the development team?

Answer (score 0):

Please log in to your openshift account and check whether your application and cartridges are up and running.

Comment: Yes, they are up and running. The problem has occurred from nothing

Answer (score 0):

From the [mod_wsgi FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions):

> Q: Why am I seeing the error message 'premature end of script headers'
>   in the Apache error logs.
>
> A: If using daemon mode, this is a symptom of the mod_wsgi daemon
>   process crashing when handling a request. You would probably also see
>   the message 'segmentation fault'. See answer for question about
>   'segmentation fault' above.
>
> This error message can also occur where you haven't configured Apache
>   correctly and your WSGI script file is being executed as a CGI script
>   instead.

It could also be possibly due to the application code hanging. This can be due to the use of third party Python modules which have a C extension component which does not work in Python sub interpreters.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

Unfortunately OpenShift has a less than ideal mod_wsgi configuration and no ready ability to override the configuration nor the start up of Apache itself. At least not unless that have made significant changes since the last time I looked.